# Counter-example to regular expression statement

Tags: automata, regular-expressions

Show a counter-example to disprove the following statement:

If $R1$ and $R2$ are two regular expressions, then $L((R1 \cup R2)^*) = L(R1^* \cup R2^*)$.

Comment: Try $R_1 = a$ and $R_2 = b$.

Comment: We're happy to help you understand the concepts but just solving exercises for you is unlikely to achieve that. You might find [this page](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1284/755) helpful in improving your question and making better use of this site in the future.  When you're asking to find a counter-example, a good place to start would be to try some possibilities (and you could show us in the question kinds of things you've already tried).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\{a\} = R1$ and $\{b\} = R2$. $'aba'$ belongs to $L((R1 \cup R2)^*)$ but not to $L(R1^* \cup R2^*)$.

explentation:

$'aba'$ belongs to $L((R1 \cup R2)^*)$ since $a$ belongs to $R1$ than with using the $*$ itiration we take $b$ from $R2$ than again we take $a$ from $R1$ by using $*$

$'aba'$ does not belong to $L(R1^* \cup R2^*)$ excepts only $a^n$ or $b^m$.

this answer is based on @Yuval Filmus